# (linear or polymonial) regression algorithm for lower bound of nearly sinusoidal data

Tags: c++, math, graph, regression, linear-regression

I need to find a curve that would fit lower poinds of my discreete data. Linear regression would be ok, but polymonial would be great :)

Usualy I do not deal with such task, so please do not be harsh on me if this is a too simple question. I'm still doing a research, but I thought that it would not hurt to also ask here.

Most important thing, is that none of points should be under this line. As far as I've found out usualy regression estimates some line in the middle of data and this is not good for me.
What algorithm could I use? I'm going to write the code in C++ , but example in any language would be great.

Graphic explanation:

[image]

Blue - my data 
Orange - good enough solution
Green - great solution!

Thanks!

Comment: I can past any code for linear regression that I've tried, but it would not help with finding the solution probably. Well, if rules need this, then I can paste it.

Comment: seems like you just need to find local minima (ie points `x_i` such that `x_i-1 > x_i < x_i+1`) and then you can use standard regression on those points

Comment: I should have mentioned, that real data is a little bit more noisy, but right, maybe I should find local min points, they will appear at the bottom and at the top of this sinusoid, an then filter those from the top, laybe with regression from the whole data, I'll try this

Comment: local **minima** are only at the bottom, not at the top ;)

Comment: Sure, I'm just saying, that an algorithm for finding them will be a little bit complex, or it will find them at the top, becouse of noise that happens there, but right sure :)

Comment: This might work. Create an initially empty second list of "filtered-in" points. Starting at the "X" value of zero, which is added to a second list by default, go to the next point. If both the previous and next points have a higher or equal "Y" value add that point to this second list. Continue to the next point until all points have been processed. When done, this list should have the data needed for the regression.

Comment: would be nice if you share test data in code form ... Do you know the properties of the signal ? like period range, is the signal ascending or superponated with some other low freq sinwave ? are the frequencies "constant" or changing ? ....

Comment: @KowalskiPaweł I added an answer with simple bin search approach. However without any more data thats all I can do without guessing ... as we do not know specs of your input data and wanted properties of the bound fit ...

Answer (score 0):

Well you did not provide us with relevant data yet so I used your image as input. The linear lower bound is computed quite simply:

1. compute bounding box for your data
2. bin search "all valid" lines in the bbox as lower bound

**Here simple C++ example:**

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
double *pnt=NULL; int pnts=0;   // input data points pnt[pnts]={ x0,y0,x1,y1,x2,y2,... } loaded during init of app from image
double fit0[4]={0,0,0,0};       // output line endpoints fit0 = { x0,y0,x1,y1 }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void compute()
    {
    int i,j;
    double x,x0,x1,y,y0,y1,yy,a,a0,a1,X0;
    // bbox
    x0=x1=pnt[0]; X0=x0;
    y0=y1=pnt[1];
    for (i=0;i<pnts;)
        {
        x=pnt[i]; i++;
        y=pnt[i]; i++;
        if (x0>x) x0=x;
        if (y0>y){y0=y; X0=x; } // X0 is the point where y is minimal
        if (x1<x) x1=x;
        if (y1<y) y1=y;
        }
    // fit0 (line)
    fit0[0]=X0;
    fit0[1]=y0;
    fit0[2]=x1;
    fit0[3]=y0;
    for (a0=y0,a1=y1,j=0;j<10;j++)          // bin search accuracy iterations
        {
        a=0.5*(a0+a1);
        for (i=0;i<pnts;)
            {
            x=pnt[i]; i++;                  // tested point from data
            y=pnt[i]; i++;
            yy=y0+((x-X0)*(a-y0)/(x1-X0));  // coresponding y value of fited line
            if (yy>y) { i=-1; break; }      // too big
            }
        if (i>=0){ a0=a; fit0[3]=a; }       // valid line
         else      a1=a;                    // invalid line
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So I set the bound as line. Its first endpoint is first global minimum from left and I binary search the second endpoint. Where its `x` is the global maximum of `x` and `y` is tested between global min and max (best solution is remembered). Here preview:

[image: preview]